# OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user <usuario>@'localhost' (using password: NO)") al intentar insertar un registro con Flask en MySQL

Tags: python, flask

Estoy intentando insertar un registro desde Python utilizando flask, y al llenar el formulario y enviarlo a la función *agrega* me envía error:

> MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'Artron'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")

No sé por qué (mi admin no tiene password).

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL 
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MySQL_HOST']='localhost'
app.config['MySQL_USER']='root'
app.config['MySQL_PASSWORD']=''
app.config['MySQL_DB']='direcciones'
mysql = MySQL(app)
@app.route('/')
def Index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/add_contact', methods=['POST'])
def agrega():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        categoria = request.form['categoria']
        nombre = request.form['nombre']
        direccion = request.form['direccion']
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute('INSERT INTO direccion_1 (categoria,nombre,direccion)VALUES (%s,%s,%s)',
        (categoria,nombre,direccion))
        mysql.connection.commit
        return 'received'
@app.route('/edit')
def edita():
    return 'Editar Contacto'
@app.route('/delete')
def elimina():
    return ("Elimina Contacto")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port = 3000, debug = True)
```

Comment: Hola. Tienes que asegurarte de que le has dado todos los permisos al usuario

Comment: Revise y mi usuario (root) tiene todos los privilegios.

Answer (score 0):

Te da error porque no está accediendo como usuario `root` si no como el usuario de tu máquina `Artron`, si te fijas en el mensaje de error:

> MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user
> '**Artron**'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")

Es un simple error tipográfico, las claves del diccionario de configuración están mal escritas (es todo es mayúsculas como se indica [aquí](https://github.com/alexferl/flask-mysqldb) y [aquí](https://pypi.org/project/Flask-MySQLdb/)), por lo que flask las ignora y usa los valores por defecto (nombre del usuario de la máquina y `localhost`).

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL 
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MYSQL_HOST']='localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_USER']='root'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD']=''
app.config['MYSQL_DB']='direcciones'
mysql = MySQL(app)
```

Comment: Me perdí. En la pregunta también están en mayúsculas: ¿cuál es la diferencia?

Comment: Que va. Si te fijas en la pregunta pone `app.config['MySQL_USER']` en lugar de `app.config['MYSQL_USER']`. La "y" está en minúscula. Por lo que flask consulta el dato `MYSQL_USER` y al no estar establecido, usa los valores por defecto. Lo mismo pasa con el resto de datos, solo que en el caso del host no da problema porque el valor por defecto también es `localhost`.

Comment: Tenés razón, buen ojo.